# getting typescript error in react + mui while creating tabs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I am creating custom hook of accordion component . I am getting below error

**export default const Tabs: OverridableComponent<TabsTypeMap<{}, ExtendButtonBase<ButtonBaseTypeMap<{}, "button">>>>**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-easley-ek3ev5?file=/src/App.tsx

```
export default function BasicTabs() {
  const { register, value } = useTabs();
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
        <Tabs {...register()} aria-label="basic tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
```

any suggestion

[image]

Comment: Your hook should return props declared in [Tabs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tabs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `useTabs` you should change change `React.ChangeEvent` to `React.SyntheticEvent` as the signature of `onChange` is `function(event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: any) => void` in `<Tabs />` : https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tabs/